# Regex to seperate a work and decimal number

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I would like to have a regex to separate a word and decimal number.

Example of an input string:

```
{[FACEBOOK23.1K],[UNKNOWN6],[SKYPE12.12M]}
```

Expected result:

```
{[FACEBOOK,23.1K],[UNKNOWN,6],[SKYPE,12.12M]}
```

So curently i am using  re.findall(r'\D+|\d+.+\d+|\d+',element)

and here element is [FACEBOOK23.1K] and it is seperating as [FACEBOOK,23.1,K]

and i tried the followig regex =re.findall(r'\D+|(\d+.+\d+)?(K|M|G|T)|(\d+)?(K|M|G|T)|\d+',element)
to get expected result as it is showing the seperation correctly on regex online simulator ,but it is not working when i am trying on my code ? >>>>

Comment: sorry [SKYPE,12.12M]}

Comment: no effort spend yourself = no help!

Comment: Hi Srinivas, please edit the question for changes and to add what you have tried so far. See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace

Comment: I am currently trying this regex "\D+|(\d+\.+\d+|\d+)?(K|M|G|T)|\d+" and regex function as re.split but it is not splitting into appropraite elements

Comment: Please add the full relevant code snippet into the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

text = '{[FACEBOOK23.1K],[UNKNOWN6],[SKYPE12.12M]}';

m = re.findall('\[([a-z]+)([^\]]+)\]', text, re.IGNORECASE);

output = '{';
i = 0
for (name,count) in m:
    if i>0:
        output += ','
    output += "["+name+","+count+"]"
    i=i+1
output += '}'

print output
```

Comment: if i have text like                                                                                         text = ['FACEBOOK23.1K','UNKNOWN6','SKYPE12.12M'];                                   and seperating like ['FACEBOOK,23.1K','UNKNOWN,6','SKYPE,12.12M']                           what can be regex?

Comment: I wrote the regex inside the findall function

Comment: Yeah i got it and tried the above scenerio also                                                           #!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
text = ['IP_ICMP_HELLO23.1K','UNKNOWN6','SKYPE12.12M'];
ele_list1=[]
for i in text:
    print i
    m = re.findall('[(a-z)(_)]+|[^\]]+', i, re.IGNORECASE);
    ele_list1.append(m)
print ele_list1

Comment: I got the output ad executing as follows  something like this http://ideone.com/N6MzWd